# “Ability to solve problems through the standard application of theoretical principles” in a position description?

Tags: application, administration, non-academic-staff

I am trying to apply for a job in a university research office, administering honour’s, master’s and PhD thesis submissions. The selection criteria are:

> 1. Demonstrated ability to apply theoretical knowledge, at degree level, in a straightforward way.
> 2. Ability to solve problems through the standard application of theoretical principles and techniques at degree level.

Can anyone tell me what they are asking for, and give examples of how one could  demonstrate these skills?

Comment: My interpretation is that they simply want someone intelligent, with an academic level of thinking but not necessarily an academic degree. But I think they also need someone capable of writing better selection criteria.

Comment: They are using annoying job description language but basically they are saying "we want someone who has some general understanding of the subject matter associated with these theses, in contrast to a position for an administrative assistant who has office skills but not necessarily technical knowledge"